# subtract 6 hours from date('g:i a', strtotime($time_date_data));

Tags: php, date

I am using the following code to transform a universal time code into something a little more user friendly.

```
$meeting_time = date('g:i a', strtotime($time_date_data));
```

But now I need to subtract 6 hours from meeting_time. Should I do it after the code above or can I work it into the same date function?

Something like:

```
$meeting_time = date('g:i a' - 6, strtotime($time_date_data));
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$meeting_time = date('g:i a', strtotime($time_date_data) - 60 * 60 * 6);
```

String-to-time (strtotime) returns a Unix Time Stamp which is in seconds (since Epoch), so you can simply subtract the 21600 seconds, before converting it back to the specified date format.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach:

```
$meeting_time = date('g:i a', strtotime('-6 hours', strtotime($time_date_data)));
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
// 6 hours, 3600 seconds in an hour
$meeting_time = date('g:i a', strtotime($time_date_data) - 6 * 3600);
```

Comment: This answer was more precise on the time calculation for me. Thank You mc10.

Answer (score 7):

The way of OO PHP:

```
$date = new DateTime(); // current time
echo 'Current: '. $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT3H55M10S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

For subtract 6 hrs:

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-01-20'); // pass $time_date_data to here
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT6H'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this:

```
$meeting_time = date('g:i a', strtotime($time_date_data));
date_add($meeting_time, - date_interval_create_from_date_string('6 hours'));
```