# How to subtract time in DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

My date and time is separated so I combine them like this

```
$mergeDateTime = new DateTime($date.' '.$time);
$currentDateTime = $mergeDateTime->format('d-m-Y H:i A);
```

I'm trying to subtract `5 hours` to it for example the date today is `08-02-2018 04:00 AM` when subtracted it should be `07-02-2018 11:00 PM`

What I tried is this `$newDate = date('d-m-Y H:i A', strtotime($currentDateTime)- (5 * 3600));`

But it returns a different result than what I'm expecting. 
Thank you in advance for the help!

---

UPDATE

I thought it was already okay

I tried this code `date('d-m-Y H:i A', strtotime($mergeDateTime->format('d-m-Y H:i A')) - 60 * 60 * 5);` But upon testing it to for example `11-02-2018
10:30 PM` it should be `05:30 PM` with the same date but I'm receiving `31-12-1969 20:00 PM`

It looks like if the result is in same date it returns like that.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214104/subtract-6-hours-from-dategi-a-strtotimetime-date-data)

I tried like this

```
date('d-m-Y H:i A', strtotime($mergeDateTime->format('d-m-Y H:i A')) - 60 * 60 * 5);
```

**
Update

Regarding my issue that if they have the same date, is that my merge date and time is always have `12 hours format` and not `24 hours` so I chnage `H` to `h` and now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [DateTime::sub()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) method, but also be sure you're setting the correct Time Zone.

To be clear, you're going to want to do something like this:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'); // See: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
$dt = new DateTime('now', $tz);
$di = new DateInterval('P5H');  // See DateInterval documentation for interval_spec given here
$currentDateTime = $dt->format('d-m-Y H:i A');
$dt->sub($di); // You can't use the return value here, since this modified the $dt object and returns it for chaining
$previousDateTime = $dt->format('d-m-Y H:i A');  // This now contains the new time
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to it, some of the answers may end up with same result....
heres my 1 cent..
   `$currentDateTime = $mergeDateTime->format('d-m-Y H:i:s);
    $currentDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($currentDateTime));
    $currentTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($currentDateTime));
    $hour_5 = '05:00:00';`

```
$a = new DateTime($currentTime);
$b = new DateTime($hour_5);
$diff = $a->diff($b);
$updated_date = $diff->format("%H:%i:%s");
$new_date_time = $currentDate.' '.$updated_date;
```

I have not yet tested it but should give you an idea...hope this works