# Woocommerce / Wordpress Adjust Order Time by -5 hours

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried to adjust the time of an order in Woocommerce a few different ways and cant seem to get it working.  Is there a ways to take this code and subtract 5 hours from the time reported back?

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

if( ! is_wp_error( $order ) ) {

   echo $order->get_date_created()->format ('M j, Y g:i A'); 
}
```

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214104/subtract-6-hours-from-dategi-a-strtotimetime-date-data

Comment: echo date( 'M j, Y g:i A', $order->get_date_created ()->getOffsetTimestamp() - 60 * 60 * 5);

Comment: Thank you!  This was definitely down the right path.  However with when I utilized this to adjust the time by -5 hours, it was subtracting 10 hours from the date and time.  I modified this to be (-60 * 60 * .12) and in Woocommerce, this subtracted 5 hours from the time.  Could it be the Woocommerce uses a different date time method to calculate and order time?  Marking this as best answer though and I appreciate your help!!

Comment: I have added an answer with some explanation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214104/subtract-6-hours-from-dategi-a-strtotimetime-date-data) describes how to perform addition or subtraction on the PHP date field and format them. In **Woocommerce**, there are predefined functions which are explained [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-datetime.php). To subtract 5 hours from the order date,

You can use **getTimestamp()** function which simply converts the date to timestamp.

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
if( ! is_wp_error( $order ) ) {
   echo date( 'M j, Y g:i A', $order->get_date_created ()->getTimestamp() - 60 * 60 * 5);
}
```

OR you can use **getOffsetTimestamp()** function. As per the definition [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/9eae43c0d4dde8916608c45b7bf44b893bca1107/includes/class-wc-datetime.php#L73), This converts the date to a timestamp along with the UTC offset (if it is not set within WordPress otherwise set to 0).

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
if( ! is_wp_error( $order ) ) {
   echo date( 'M j, Y g:i A', $order->get_date_created ()->getOffsetTimestamp() - 60 * 60 * 5);
}
```

Use of **getTimestamp()** function will eliminate your additional 5 hours subtraction step, as you explained in the comments